# How to configure wpa_supplicant.conf for 802.1x network?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, wpa-supplicant, 802.1x

I have a raspberry pi zero w and I'm totally new to the device and to Linux. I'd like to configure the raspberry pi such that I can access it by ssh through an 802.1x secured network. I've contacted the admin and they don't know what lines to write into the wpa_supplicant.conf file to get it to work.

This is what I have so far

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETWORK-NAME"
    psk=NONE
}
```

I should add that I've added some lines in the config.txt and the cmdline.txt to ssh by usb. I've used [this](https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb) tutorial to do that and it worked just fine. I don't know if I need to revert these settings to get ssh via wifi to work.

So I have three questions: first, how do I setup the wpa_supplicant.conf file for. 802.1x? Second, do I need to revert any of the settings I've changed when I set up ssh via USB? Third, is there a way that I can access my pi via ssh through both USB and wifi?

Comment: A 802.1x secured network can be either wired or wireless. If wireless, then a more specific term like *WPA2-secured* or even *WPA2-PSK secured* would be more common. WPA2 defines the encryption used, PSK indicates a simple network password is being used. So is your wifi network using just a network password, some kind of certificate authentication, or something else?

Comment: The USB access in the tutorial you linked is based on the Pi Zero presenting itself to the other computer as a USB network adapter, and using ZeroConf networking to sort out IP addresses and names. So any `wpa_supplicant.conf` settings should have no effect at all to it.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to revert any changes that I've made to connect via USB before I can connect via wifi?

Comment: No, there is no need to revert anything of that - you'll just essentially have two separate network interfaces in the Pi Zero: one will be wireless, and another will be wired (actually USB). Each can have its own set of settings. Since you are relying on ZeroConf on the wired/USB interface, it will have no default gateway, and so the existence of the USB connection will have no effect at all on configuring the wireless connection.